# Is it better to use generator or list when I need to go back to the start often?

Tags: python, list, generator

I want to sum the divisors of a large list of numbers, and to do so, I used a prime numbers generator :

```
def sieve_of_eratosthenes(limit):
    # Initialize the primality list
    a = [False] * 2 + [True] * (limit-2)

    for (i, isprime) in enumerate(a):
        if isprime:
            yield i
            # Mark factors non-prime
            for n in range(i*i, limit, i):     
                a[n] = False
```

Since what I want to do is something like:

```
for n in numbers_list:
    s = 0
    for p in sieve_of_eratosthenes(limit):
        if not x % p:
            s += p
```

I wonder would it be better just to create a generator once, and then turn it into a list, resulting in a large object I create only once, or keep creating the generator in each iteration (since I'll need to start from the beginning each time).

Are generators supposed to be used like this, or are lists the right solution, or maybe this is just a simple trade-off of memory / run-time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***There are two choices : keeping memory low  or runtime low  .***

**low Memory :**
Since you wouldn't modify any element in the generator or accessing the elements by indexes,it's better to use the generator as they return only one object in the memory .But you have to run the generator function every i in the loop .

**Low runtime :**
Using a list generated only one time before for loop .

```
def sieve_of_eratosthenes(limit):
    # Initialize the primality list
    a = [False] * 2 + [True] * (limit-2)

    for (i, isprime) in enumerate(a):
        if isprime:
            yield i
            # Mark factors non-prime
            for n in range(i*i, limit, i):     
                a[n] = False

limits = list(sieve_of_eratosthenes(limit))
for n in numbers_list:
    s = 0
    for p in limits:
        if not x % p:
            s += p
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for this case the list would be better but you can test if for yourself using the python timeit module:

```
from timeit import timeit

limit = value

def f1():
    #code using list

def f2():
    #code using generator

print( 'List', timeit('f1(limit)', setup=' from __main__ import f1, f2,limit') )
print( 'Generator', timeit('f2(limit)', setup=' from __main__ import f1, f2,limit') )
```

it'll print the time it takes to run code about 10**6 times... if this is too long simply add an extra argument in the timeit function called number. e.g for 100 runs

```
print( 'List', timeit('f1(limit)', setup=' from __main__ import f1, f2,limit', number=100) )
```

Comment: if you use any global variable that is used outside the function you are importing from main remember to include it in the set up import